# Grails 2.1.4 - Database Migration - Error on dbm-gorm-diff

Tags: database, grails, database-migration

I need to change my database. For this I installed the Database Migration Plugin.

```
plugins {
   …
   runtime ':database-migration:1.3.2'
}
```

I found a tutorial about the usage of [this plugin.](http://wpgreenway.com/posts/grails-db-migration-tutorial/)

My steps are:

```
  grails dbm-generate-changelog changelog.groovy
  grails dbm-changelog-sync
```

After these two steps I changed one Domain class from:

```
class Event {
     ...
     Date lastAccessed
}
```

to:

```
class Event {
     ...
     Date dateCreated
     Date lastUpdated
}
```

According to the tutorial and documentation I need to run now:

```
grails dbm-gorm-diff
```

I did this

```
grails dbm-gorm-diff add-timestamps-to-event.groovy --add
```

On this part I'm getting the error.

Stacktrace:

```
| Starting dbm-gorm-diff
12:38:20,561 - ERROR - org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.DefaultGrailsPlugin  - Error     configuration scaffolding: Error creating bean with name 'instanceControllersApi': Singleton   bean creation not allowed while the singletons of this factory are in destruction (Do not   request a bean from a BeanFactory in a destroy method implementation!)
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationNotAllowedException: Error creating bean with name 'instanceControllersApi': Singleton bean creation not allowed while the singletons of this factory are in destruction (Do not request a bean from a BeanFactory in a destroy method implementation!)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

I have no idea where this comes from.

Thanks very much for any suggestions.

Comment: Thanks to the Facebook Grails Page (especially Michael A.). [GPDATABASEMIGRATION-120](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPDATABASEMIGRATION-120) The last comment is the fix for my problem. https://github.com/ph4t/grails-database-migration/commit/68fff38397157740ee4d993c8bb67811a0f021bb